# Swagger UI conditionally hide endpoint based on environment

Tags: java, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

i would like to conditionally hide an endpoint i put in just for dev and test environments but i am having trouble...

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
String deployEnv;

@Profile("!prod")
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation(summary="this is just used in dev and test", hidden=#{deployEnv.toLowerCase().indexOf('prod')>=0})
...
public String generateToken() {
...
}
```

i've tried different variations of spel to make the hidden field work but to no avail. of course, if i just use true or false hard coded then it works fine but that's not what i want.

Comment: What library/framework do you use - Springfox, Springdoc, ...?

Comment: i use springdoc-openapi-ui 1.4.3

Comment: do you want to hide the endpoint or only the documentation?

Comment: "Any `@Component, @Configuration` or `@ConfigurationProperties` (...) can be marked with `@Profile`" ...[Spring Boot Doc:Core:Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles)

Comment: yes, i had the @Profile in my post since the beginning. it works to stop the use of the endpoint but no one wants to see something they can't use. so i want to hide the endpoint from being displayed, in prod only, by the swagger ui. that's what my question is all about.

Comment: after reading the error i get: "element value must be a constant expression", and then reading this... https://riptutorial.com/java/example/26261/constant-expressions i have come to the conclusion that it is not possible. the value must be evaluated at compile time to a literal.

Comment: also, doesn't look like the @Profile("!prod") isn't working either. i changed it to @Profile("!local") and a ran the app on my local and deployEnv was "local" but it still went into the controller method.